# How to check if a specific page uses a page template?

Tags: page-template

I'm trying to get a page which uses a specific template. I have the page_id.
Here is my code :

```
$pids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare(
  "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} 
   WHERE post_author = %d AND post_status = 'publish' 
   AND post_type='page'", $user->ID
) );

foreach($pids as $post_id)
{
   wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $tag, $taxonomy );

   // I need permalink only if that page use a specific template (say blog.php)
   $permalink_n = get_permalink($post_id);

   set_cimyFieldValue( $user_id, 'HOMEPAGE', $permalink_n );
}
```

Comment: Please indent and format the codes well for better reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page template is set in a post meta field keyed `'_wp_page_template'` so, instead of using raw `$wpdb` query, you can run a `WP_Query` using `'author'` argument and `meta_query` to retrieve pages from a specific author that also have a specific templates:

```
$q = new WP_Query( array(
  'author' => $user->ID,
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'meta_query' => array( array('key' => '_wp_page_template', 'value' => 'blog.php') )
) );

if ( $q->found_posts > 0 ) {
  foreach ( $q->posts as $post ) {
    // all pages returned have the template `'blog.php'`
    wp_set_post_terms( $post->ID, $tag, $taxonomy );
    $permalink_n = get_permalink($post);
    set_cimyFieldValue( $user->ID, 'HOMEPAGE', $permalink_n );
  }
}
```

If you want retrieve all pages from an author, but do something for all pages and something else only for some other pages you can

```
$q = new WP_Query( array(
  'author' => $user->ID,
  'post_type' => 'page'
) );

if ( $q->found_posts > 0 ) {
  foreach ( $q->posts as $post ) {

    wp_set_post_terms( $post->ID, $tag, $taxonomy );

    $template = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );

    if ( $template === 'blog.php' ) {
      $permalink_n = get_permalink($post);
      set_cimyFieldValue( $user->ID, 'HOMEPAGE', $permalink_n );
    }

  }
}
```